# In Magento template Cattheme-se101 top nav bar CSS, how to achieve two lines in one block?

Tags: javascript, css, magento

Here is the theme demo: http://demo.cattheme.com/se101/
In aprox. line 20 there is the link to the .css file needed, being right now: http://demo.cattheme.com/se101/media/css/0faa57547575da2b7b0c8d2cc713a5f2.css

I believe line 712 that reads: #nav  li a.level-top {display:block; padding:0 7px; line-height:39px; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);color: #FFFFFF; font-size:11px; text-transform:uppercase;} controls the left side of the top navegation bar
that currently on the demo is:

FURNITURE | ELECTRONICS | APPAREL | IPHONE AND IPAD | FASHION | CAR TECH | AND SO ON...

Instead, I would like this block to have the possibility of two lines and should read like this:

```
ABBIE     | ELECTRONICS | POPULAR  | IPHONES | FASHION | CAR         | AND SO ON...
FURNITURE |             | APPAREL  | & IPADS |         | TECHNOLOGY  |
```

I tried changing the display for inline, but it didn't work. I also tried with the width reduced, but did not work either.

Is it because I have to change something else somewhere else?
Appreciate your help!

Comment: This is a question about a specific Magento template, so you are probably better off asking on the Magento forums, as it's not clear it's a css query. In any case, you should be using tools like Firebug to help you track it down. Putting a <br /> in the topic heading may be a start, but unlikely given the complexity of the css. Lastly, please format your css code: it's very difficult to read.

Comment: Appreciate it Pete. I will give it a try to each of the options you suggested. It is not my code, but from a template purchased and now I need to make the nav bar to have two be able to display 2 lines in 1 block. Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

- The containing elements (whatever they may be) need to have a defined width.
- The containing elements **should** have a defined height.
- The text should be set to `display: inline;`
- You will need to adjust the `line-height` of the text.